# Unable to load qtcreatorcdbext.dll when remote debugging with Qt 15.3.1

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-creator, remote-debugging

[I've been following the instructions here for remote debugging with CDB](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#remote-debugging).

I'm able to connect to the remote machine's CDB session fine and see the output, but when I try to add breakpoints on the local machine running Qt Creator I end up getting the following error:

```
The call to LoadLibrary(qtcreatorcdbext) failed, Win32 error 0n126
    "The specified module could not be found."
```

I've created a system environment variable _NT_DEBUGGER_EXTENSION_PATH that points to the folder containing qtcreatorcdbext.dll on the remote machine. The DLL is the 64-bit version, and I'm running the 64-bit version of CDB on a 64-bit application that was compiled with the MSVC2017 64-bit compiler. If I replace the qtcreatorcdbext.dll with the 32-bit version, I get the following error when specifying a breakpoint:

```
The call to LoadLibrary(qtcreatorcdbext) failed, Win32 error 0n193
    "%1 is not a valid Win32 application."
```

So it looks like it's able to find the DLL but not actually load the 64-bit version. I've also verified that I'm running the same version of CDB on both machines.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I had to use this tools https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies in order to investigate the dependencies regarding qtcreatorcdbext.dll and python35.dll and see which dlls were missing on my setup.